# I want to find 3 different users in the same mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have one order table with 3 different userids (one that placed an order request, one that ordered the order and one that received the order) and one user table. I want to get out all 3 different first names and last names from the user table in one select query. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Can you show us your table create statements, I.e. DDL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight-forward case of <s>self-join</s> a multi-way join from one table to the same other table (3 times in this example), which requires the use of table aliases.  Using table aliases for multiple appearances of a single table in a single query is a rite of passage in the SQL world.

```
SELECT u1.firstname, u1.lastname,
       u2.firstname, u2.lastname,
       u3.firstname, u3.lastname,
       o.order_num, o.placed_order_req, o.ordered_order, o.received_order
  FROM Orders AS o
  JOIN Users AS u1 ON o.placed_order_req   = u1.user_id
  JOIN Users AS u2 ON o.ordered_order_req  = u2.user_id
  JOIN Users AS u3 ON o.received_order_req = u3.user_id;
```

Comment: @Hammerite - you're right; it requires multiple table aliases to the same table name, which is also needed with a self-join, but this is a multi-way join from one table to another.